# Looping through user input and adding it to a list of unknown length

Tags: python, list, loops

The code ask the user 5 questions and they will answer it and then those 5 answers will be one element of a new list of unknown length as

What I mean is I don't know how many horses the user will bet on one day. If the user bets 6 horses in one day then the new list will have have 6 elements with each element being a list of horse,stake,odds,result,book.

So I am looking for a code which will keep adding to the new list until the user says "No" to the question "Would you like to add a selection?"

```
while True:

    add_selection =raw_input("Would you like to add a selection?")
    if add_selection == "Yes":

            selection = raw_input('Horse: ')
            print selection

            stake = float(raw_input('Stake: '))
            print stake

            odds = float(raw_input('Odds: '))
            print odds

            result = ["Win", "Lose", "Refund"]
            result = (raw_input('Result: '))

            if result == "Win":
                print stake * odds
            elif result == "Lose":
                print 0
            elif result == "Refund":
                print stake

            book = raw_input('Book: ')
            print book

            list=[selection,stake,odds,result,book]
            print list


    elif add_selection == "No":
        return 0
```

Sorry if this is too much but I tired to work it out all day using google and browsing this website but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add it all to some final list?

```
final_list = []
while True:

    add_selection =raw_input("Would you like to add a selection?").lower()
    if add_selection == "yes":

            selection = raw_input('Horse: ')
            print selection

            stake = float(raw_input('Stake: '))
            print stake

            odds = float(raw_input('Odds: '))
            print odds

            result = (raw_input('Result: '))

            if result == "Win":
                print stake * odds
            elif result == "Lose":
                print 0
            elif result == "Refund":
                print stake

            book = raw_input('Book: ')
            print book

            final_list.append([selection,stake,odds,result,book])
            print final_list


    else:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you this one works after you add final_list[] at the end and edit the indents, thanks a lot m8!

Answer (score 0):

Create a list outside the scope of the loop then append to it based on user input.  When they enter "No", leave the loop with `break` if you want to stay in the function, `return` if you want to leave the function.

You need to declare `inputs` before the loop in order to access it outside of the loop.  Otherwise, it won't be "in scope" anymore and accessible to code.  Instead of just printing inputs, you'll probably want to return it to whatever function is calling your menu.

```
inputs = []
while True:

    add_selection =raw_input("Would you like to add a selection?")
    if add_selection == "Yes":
            selection = raw_input('Horse: ')
            print selection

            stake = float(raw_input('Stake: '))
            print stake

            odds = float(raw_input('Odds: '))
            print odds

            result = ["Win", "Lose", "Refund"]
            result = (raw_input('Result: '))

            if result == "Win":
                print stake * odds
            elif result == "Lose":
                print 0
            elif result == "Refund":
                print stake

            book = raw_input('Book: ')
            print book

            list=[selection,stake,odds,result,book]
            print list

            inputs.append(list)

    elif add_selection == "No":
        break
print inputs
```

https://ideone.com/s9fHXo